# how to get y-Axis points in NVD3 chart

Tags: angular, d3.js, nvd3.js, linechart, angular-nvd3

I'm working with `NVD3` charts with `angular2` following [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/T4i7Zh?p=preview). I'm getting line chart fine. In line chart on mouse over tooltip gets shown on Yaxis 3 points.

YAxis have Line lines so three points we need a display on somewhere in the page.We tried to like this

```
yAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'Voltage (v)',
          tickFormat: function(d){
          this.username  = d3.format('.02f')(d); 
          return d3.format('.02f')(d);
          },
          axisLabelDistance: -10
        }
```

HTML

```
<div>
      <nvd3 [options]="options" [data]="data"></nvd3>
      <p>Hello {{username}}</p>
</div>
```

We are not getting anything. What do I miss?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The plunker link you gave seems to be working correctly. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @jeznag thanks for reply .yes that plunker working correctly.On Line chart we are showing tootip,On tootip showing 3 points .We need show  those 3 points some where in page like <p>Hello {{points}}</p>.Please guide to us